# Is $2^\pi$ always equal to 8.82498...?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation

A complex power is defined as:

$z^w = e^{w \ln(z)}$

Since $\ln(z)$ is multi-valued:

$z^w = e^{w(\ln|z| + i(\theta + 2k\pi))}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$

In this case, $\theta = 0$ because $z = 2$ is a positive real number, and also $w = \pi$, so:

$2^\pi = e^{\pi(\ln|2| + i \cdot 2k\pi)}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$2^\pi = e^{\pi \ln|2|} \cdot e^{i \cdot 2k \cdot \pi^2}$

Using the properties of logarithms and Euler's identity:

$2^\pi = |2|^\pi \cdot (\cos(2k\pi^2) + i \sin(2k\pi^2))$

Which will lead to infinite different values, but the principal value is with $k = 0$:

$2^\pi \approx |2|^\pi \approx 8.82498$

But another possible value is for example with $k = 1$:

$2^\pi \approx |2|^\pi \cdot (\cos(2\pi^2) + i \sin(2\pi^2)) \approx 5.55693 + i \cdot 6.85571$

Am I right or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: You said it yourself. $\ln(z)$ is multivalued. You are writing a constant with a multivalued function, you will get extraneous values. $2^{\pi}$ is a constant and its value is the principal value you had.

Comment: If $a,b$ are real numbers and $a>0$ , $a^b$ is not multi-valued and can uniquely be computed since the ln is uniquely determined for positive real numbers. So , $2^{\pi}$ has only one possible value , namely the real number we get in the complex version.

Answer (score 2):

The number $2^{\pi}$ is by common convention the real number only. We can read in *[Complex Analysis](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=CHEL/385)* by L. Ahlfors in section 3.4 *The Logarithm*:

> **(L. Ahlfors)**: By convention the logarithm of a positive number shall always mean the real logarithm, unless the contrary is stated. The symbol $a^b$, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary complex numbers except for the condition $a\ne 0$, is always interpreted as an equivalent of $\exp(b\log a)$. If $a$ is restricted to positive numbers, $\log a$ shall be real, and $a^b$ has a single value. Otherwise $\log a$ is the complex logarithm, and $a^b$ has in general infinitely many values which differ by factors $e^{2\pi i n b}$.

Comment: Is there a convention that extends to Modular fields, for $a^b \bmod c$ ?

Comment: @OlderAmateur: I'm sorry, I'm not aware of any such convention.